# List in react native is not displayed

Tags: javascript, reactjs, native

I want to display a list in react native but what shows up on the screen is:

> item.name item.name item.name item.name item.name

and if I hover over 'item' it says

> 'item' is declared but its value is never read.

If i delete the *Text* tag then *item* is visible but can't display the names because it has to be surrounded by Text tag.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { StyleSheet,Text, View,TouchableOpacity,AsyncStorage,FlatList } from 
'react-native';
import { createStackNavigator} from "react-navigation"

export default class ListPage extends Component {


render(){
const { navigation } = this.props; 
return (
  <View style={styles.container}>
    <FlatList
      data = {[{name:'bob'},{name:'bob'},{name:'bob'},{name:'bob'},{name:'bob'}]}
     keyExtractor={(x,i) => i.toString()}
      renderItem={({ item }) => 
      <Text>item.name</Text>
    }
    />
  </View>
);
}


} 

 const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    container: {
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: '#95a5a6',

},
  })
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your data is an array of objects. You forgot to wrap the renderItem function with curly braces. It should be:

```
  renderItem={({ item }) => 
  <Text>{item.name}</Text>
```

Instead of:

```
  renderItem={({ item }) => 
  <Text>item.name</Text>
```